# li a:hover moving other <li> elements

Tags: html, css

When I hover over my list item, the other `<li>`s are pushed to the side.

I think it is do do with the `padding` but I'm not sure.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Mur6K/

CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 15px;
}

li a{

    }

    li a:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #3f82a3;
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #4683bc;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above, padding for the left and right side of the regular li (when not hovering) is 7px, it's because you are adding `border:1px` when hovering.

You can give like below too

```
li a{
   padding: 7px; 
}
```

this will also give you the same result.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers like this. If you need to improve your answer in the future, edit it. I'm deleting the other one since this one was accepted./

Answer (score 0):

change your css

```
li a{
   padding:6px; 
}
```

Corrected your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MuhammedAbduRafi/Mur6K/1/).